# How to move and modify files on shared hosting with Yii2 Framework?

Tags: content-management-system, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am building a CMS for my client website using advanced template(Yii2 Framework).

The problem is:

Now, I need to host the files on shared server hosting. The server has a directory called public_html. I referred [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-shared-hosting.md) guide. According to the guide, I made changes to the directory, moved the frontend/web to public_html. Now the pages are broken. According to the guide it states that after moving the directory, we need to make changes to some index files.

I tried to move the files but I was unable to modify the index files. I was confused with the process. Please help to know which files need to be moved and modified?

Comment: Tell when the problem is, what have you tried, what error you are having etc. "unable to modify the index files" what does that means? you can edit them with any text editor. Read the tutorial again, it is quite good.

Comment: Hi, the guide says, " In each case you need to adjust paths in index.php and index-test.php." What changes need to be done to these files?

Comment: there are files that are included or required in there. Change them to fit the changes that you have made.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. I faced same the issue and here is the solution. We need to change the www/index.php to like this

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../frontend/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../frontend/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../frontend/config/main-local.php')
);`enter code here`

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `kartik-v/yii2-app-practical`. It is already customized for shared hosting environment